# Getteing error message on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT name 
FROM Staff 
join Staff on Room.StaffNumber=Staff.StaffID
join Room on Room.ModuleID =Module.Modulecode 
where Module.Moduletitle='Website Production';
```

I am using query to return information but receiving error message

```
Not unique table/alias: 'Staff'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where in the from clause do we have Module?

`SELECT name 
FROM Staff 
join Staff on Room.StaffNumber=Staff.StaffID
join Room on Room.ModuleID =Module.Modulecode 
where Module.Moduletitle='Website Production';`

Shouldn't this rather be:

```
    SELECT s.name
      FROM staff s
      JOIN room r
        ON s.staffid = r.staffnumber
      JOIN module m
        ON r.moduleid = m.modulecode
     WHERE m.moduletitle = 'Webstie Production';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining 3 tables together: `Staff`, `Staff`, and `Room` (self-join on `Staff`).  If that were truly your intention, then you would need to distinguish between the two `Staff` tables by aliasing them, something like this:

```
SELECT s1.name 
  FROM Staff s1 
  JOIN Staff s2 ON s1.StaffID = s2.StaffId
  ...
```

(you would also want to be explicit in the selection (`s1.name`) to say from which table the name is coming from.

But it doesn't look like that was really your intention.  I would guess you were trying to join the three tables `Staff`, `Room`, and `Module`, something along these lines:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM Staff s
  JOIN Room r ON (r.StaffNumber = s.StaffID)
  JOIN Module m ON (m.Modulecode = r.ModuleID)
  WHERE m.Moduletitle = 'Website Production';
```